# How do I recover accidentally deleted/canceled meetings in Outlook 2013 calendar?

Tags: data-recovery, microsoft-outlook-2013

While trying to remove recurrence of events, I accidentally deleted the meeting requests (sent by others) and canceled the ones (created by me).

I want to recover those items. How can I do that?

Comment: They should be located in the `Deleted Items` folder.  If they are not located in that folder then they cannot be recovered.

Comment: @Ramhound I think they might be also available under `Recover Deleted Items` menu in case they were removed from Deleted Items. I belive mfcmapi tool would be able to find them if not visible in GUI.

Answer (score 5):

All deleted items should be in your `Deleted items` folder under `Inbox` or if you've deleted them from deleted items, they should be available for restoration under `Tools`->`Recover Deleted Items` for some time.

You might find [this guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/restore-deleted-items-in-outlook-HA010355039.aspx) and [this guide](http://www.addintools.com/documents/outlook/where-recover-deleted-item.html) useful. Oh! and [this one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/how-to-undo-after-accidentally-deleting-calendar/e204945f-b116-4e68-82de-002d54eb7e21) as well.

Edit:

> Actually, restore deleted calendar got the same steps as restore deleted messages. You must be a Microsoft Exchange Server account.
>
> 1.In the folder from which the item was deleted, or in the Deleted Items folder, on the Folder tab, in the Clean Up group, click Recover
>   Deleted Items.   Note: If the Recover Deleted Items command is missing:
>
> > An Exchange account is required for this command to appear. If you are
> >     using an Exchange account and don’t see the command, contact your
> >     Exchange administrator.
>
> 2.Click an item, and then click Recover Selected Items .   Note: Your Exchange administrator specifies the retention time for deleted items.
>   After this time elapses, deleted items cannot be restored.

Found in [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/de92c7c0-84e8-4808-bd31-4e3da2bd5483/how-to-restore-deleted-calendar-items-from-recover-deleted-items-in-outlook-2010?forum=outlook).

Comment: I cancel/delete a meeting item in `Calendar`, not in `Inbox`

Comment: You can find instructions for deleted calendar items under this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/de92c7c0-84e8-4808-bd31-4e3da2bd5483/how-to-restore-deleted-calendar-items-from-recover-deleted-items-in-outlook-2010?forum=outlook

Comment: Please update your answer to clarify that and to get accepted when it works

Comment: @NamGVU I've updated my answer with solution provided under mentioned URL.